# How To Change Windows Time Format In Date/Time Window In Windows 10?

Tags: date, time, format

I have my short time format set to HH:MM:ss which includes the leading zero. But, instead the time format doesn't include the leading zero. Is it possible to include the leading zero into this time format?

EDIT: I'm currently not allowed to post images, the time format I am on about is when you click the time and date in the bottom right hand corner of Windows 10 and it then displays it in the top of the box that appears.

Many thanks,

William

Comment: This doesn't sound like a *programming* question, but one about "using Windows 10". Where does the programming part come in?

Comment: This website isn't all about programming is it? If so, which sort of forum should I post this on?

Comment: Yes it is. Please read the [tour]. It sounds like you probably want SuperUser. (Note that Stack Exchange sites aren't forums, either...)

Comment: Oh, I didn't see anywhere that it was specifically programming based. But, thanks for letting me know. :)